# Why do I get the empty tuple if I type / in iPython?

Tags: ipython

Open up iPython and type this:

```
/
```

Hit enter and wonder about the result:

```
()
```

You cannot assign it, my guess it has something to do with the shell functionality.

Edit:

You can assign it with:

```
 p = Out[xx]
```

But not directly:

```
 p = /
```

will give:

```
SyntaxError
```

It is indeed an empty tuple.

Comment: In the Python interpreter, you get a `SyntaxError`. This is iPython specific.

Comment: Ah, yes you are right, I forget to add the tag. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a convenience feature for callable objects/names. It's not an empty tuple, but parentheses completion. From iPython's help system (`?`):

> - Auto-parentheses and auto-quotes (adapted from Nathan Gray's LazyPython)
>
>   1. Auto-parentheses
>
>      Callable objects (i.e. functions, methods, etc) can be invoked like
>        this (notice the commas between the arguments)::
>
>      In [1]: callable_ob arg1, arg2, arg3
>
>      and the input will be translated to this::
>
>      callable_ob(arg1, arg2, arg3)
>
>      This feature is off by default (in rare cases it can produce
>        undesirable side-effects), but you can activate it at the command-line
>        by starting IPython with `--autocall 1`, set it permanently in your
>        configuration file, or turn on at runtime with `%autocall 1`.
>
>      You can force auto-parentheses by using '/' as the first character
>        of a line.  For example::
>
>      In [1]: /globals             # becomes 'globals()'

Comment: Great bit of obscure knowledge.

Comment: Its not that obscure; its mentioned in the [documentation](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/interactive/reference.html#automatic-parentheses-and-quotes)